# How to use a list in django query

Tags: django

I have a list of owner_id and I want to use that list in a django query, but it gives me the following error:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Here's the code:

```
d = DispatchPlan.objects.filter(Q(created_on__range=[date_to,date_from]) | Q(owner_id = [3,2,5]))
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `id__in` like this:

```
d = DispatchPlan.objects.filter(Q(created_on__range=[date_to,date_from]) | Q(owner_id__in = [3,2,5]))
```